# Thiessen Polygon in arcgis-10.1

Tags: arcgis, gis

I have a point shapefile of rain gauge stations (with data) which I want to use to create a Thiessen polygons over a basin/watershed (another shapefile). All the raingauge points are located within the spatial extents of the basin/watershed. 
I want my Thiessen polygon to cover the whole basin like this:

[image]

I used ArcToolbox/Analysis Tools/Proximity/Create Thiessen Polygons to create it and i got something like this:

[image: Thiessen Polygon covering just part of the basin]

I would like my polygons to cover the whole basin area.

Comment: This looks like a question that would be far more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your extents to another shapefile (or see other options).  When you have your polygon tool open, you go into Advance (bottom RH corner) > Extents, you should find it.